# Diferencia File.ReadAllBytes (C#) con su tamaño en KB (según windows)

Tags: c#

Estoy configurando una petición de envío de adjunto en mensajes SMS y tengo un problema de restricción de envío según lo que aplico en web.config. No llego a encontrar documentación sobre por qué indica windows en un fichero tiene 4,938 KB y la función ReadAllBytes en C# me devuelve 5055528 bytes. ¿Me podéis indicar relación entre estos dos valores? Si el límite en webconfig es de 5MB por lectura de bytes se está pasando, pero según Windows no llega.

Comment: 1KB NO es igual a 1000B

Comment: @SJuan76 1 KB sí es igual a 1000B, sin embargo 1 KiB es igual a 1024B, pero la mayoría de las veces no escriben KiB, sino KB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dan la misma medida expresada en diferentes unidades.

Si nos vamos al sistema internacional, el prefijo Kilo (K) indica una multiplicidad de 1000, que es 10^3 (M es 10^6, G es 10^9 y así sucesivamente). Sin embargo, en la informática se suele utilizar la base 2, no base 10, y 2^10 es 1024.

Para múltiplos de 1024 en 1024 unidades tenemos variantes de esos prefijos del sistema internacional. Por ejemplo 1 Kibibyte (KiB) son 1024 Bytes, 1 Mibibyte (MiB) son 1024 KiB (2^20 Bytes), 1GiB son 10^30 Bytes, y así sucesivamente.

Si divides el número de Bytes (5055528) entre 1024 obtienes un total de 4937,0390625 KiB, y quedándonos con la aproximación hacia el entero superior, son 4938 KiB.

Por tanto, aunque ponga KB, está mal escrito, no son Kilobytes, son Kibibytes, o KiB.

Generalmente nadie escribe KiB, o MiB. Pero debes tener en cuenta que dependiendo del entorno en el que estés, los prefijos (K, M, G) significarán una cosa u otra. Por ejemplo, al medir la capacidad de un disco duro, o el ancho de banda de una red K significa 1000 (1KB son 10^3 Bytes, pero en las redes medimos en bits, por lo que un 1Kb, o Kilobit, son 10^3 bits). Si hablamos de memoria RAM, KB (que está mal escrito) se suele referir a KiB. No siempre es así, pero con realizar la división lo puedes comprobar.

Como dato adicional, en el sistema internacional de unidades el prefijo para *kilo* es k minúscula, pero para magnitudes superiores sí son letras mayúsculas (M, G, T), por lo que lo correcto sería decir 1kB para 10^3 Bytes y 1 kb para 10^3 bits. Sin embargo, en la informática habitualmente (por falta de rigurosidad) se escribe KB, independientemente de si son kilobytes, kibibytes o kilobits.